# Focus problem on tvOS app when moving from a view to another

Tags: swift, tvos

Hy,

I have a view on tvOS that contains two views of different sizes. When I move from the left view I want to focus the items from the left view, but this is not happening.

Here is how it looks:[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IX6HX.png)

The **left view** is a **tableView** and the **right view** is a **UIView** that has a **textField** on top. I want when I move from tableview to focus on textField. But now it does not happen.

I created a focusGuide on the **mainController** that contains those two views that has the same anchors as **mainController** and it doesn't work. Like this:

```
 private func setupFocusGuide(){
    self.sideFocusGuide = UIFocusGuide()
    view.addLayoutGuide(self.sideFocusGuide!)
    self.sideFocusGuide?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mainView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    self.sideFocusGuide?.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mainView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    self.sideFocusGuide?.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mainView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    self.sideFocusGuide?.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mainView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    self.sideFocusGuide?.preferredFocusEnvironments = [self.rightView]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use another `UIFocusGuide` that switches focus between `UITableView` and `UITextField`:

```
private var focusGuideTextFieldAndTableView: UIFocusGuide!
```

Initialise it:

```
focusGuideTextFieldAndTableView = UIFocusGuide()
view.addLayoutGuide(focusGuideTextFieldAndTableView)
focusGuideTextFieldAndTableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
focusGuideTextFieldAndTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.topAnchor).isActive = true
focusGuideTextFieldAndTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
focusGuideTextFieldAndTableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.leftAnchor).isActive = true
focusGuideTextFieldAndTableView.preferredFocusEnvironments = [textField]
```

Switch `preferredFocusEnvironments` in `didUpdateFocus(in:with:)`:

```
override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    super.didUpdateFocus(in: context, with: coordinator)
    if context.nextFocusedView == textField {
        focusGuideTextFieldAndTableView.preferredFocusEnvironments = [tableView]
    } else if context.previouslyFocusedView == textField {
        focusGuideTextFieldAndTableView.preferredFocusEnvironments = [textField]
    }
}
```

Comment: This works a lot better than simply setting the preferredFocusEnvironments variable. Thanks.